# How to create subcollection indexes at Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have googled and checked the Cloud Firestore documentation and found nothing about how to declare subcollections indexes. I have declared something like this

```
...{    
  "collectionId": "user/{uid}/feeds",
  "fields": [..]
}...
```

and in the indexes tab it is stored like this

```
__escuser~1{uid}~1feeds__
```

No idea if I created properly it or not.

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by "subcollection indexes"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: there is user collection and each `user` collection have another `feeds` collection and I'm not able to add indexes for sub collections ~ https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

Comment: @Shaxrillo I have seen mention somewhere that this feature was planned but not implemented yet. And it would not be implemented in beta. I also want this feature

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you go to create an index, it actually tells you to run the query you want to create an index for once manually and then it will generate a URL you can copy paste into the browser et voila!

[image]

This is how you do it:

1. Create a new dir
2. `npm init`
3. `npm i --save firebase-admin`
4. Create `index.js`
5. Put the following function in the document

   ```
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const serviceAccount = require('./firebase-creds.json');

    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: 'https://projectId.firebaseio.com'
    });

    const db = admin.firestore();

    function runQuery() {
      db
      .collection('users')
      .doc(someRandomUserId)
      .collection('feed')
      .where('read', '==', false)
      .where('timestamp', '<=', 1509889854742) //Or something else
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
    };
    runQuery();
   ```
6. Run `node index.js`

This will spit someting like this out:

`{ Error: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-projectID/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=longRandomString ...}`

Copy the link and paste it into your browser.

[image]

**Update**

To add the index manually (via the CLI) you can do the following:

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionId": "feed",
      "fields": [
        { "fieldPath": "read", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
        { "fieldPath": "timestamp", "mode": "ASCENDING" },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Or simply go in to the admin panel in your database and add the index for feeds there.

Comment: Thank you @Chris But I want to add it manually not by auto generated url

Comment: Ok, it's going to be the same result regardless, but see the above. You don't specify a 'subcollection path' but just the collection id @Shaxrillo

Comment: @Chris, but what is a "collection id"?  I have multiple collections with the same name in different parts of my firestore hierarchy.  e.g. /cars/{carIds}/models and /magazines/{magazineId}/models
If I just put an index on "models" will firebase apply index to both of these collections?  Do I have to give all of my collections unique names if I want to be able to index them independently of each other?

Comment: @Chris I think you misunderstand the point of "subcollection index" he want. It not index to specific collection in one document but index for each collection with the same name in each document. Which is in the plan of firestore but not exist yet

Comment: @Thaina are you sure this doesn't exist yet?  Can you point to where you read this?

Comment: @JeffPadgett I have read firebase blog every day every week for a year. They never announce update on this feature. But the mentioning on "the plan to support" is scatter around in some place that was request this feature

Comment: @Thaina  Thanks for getting back to me.  Read this discussion I had with Sam Stern - He says the indexes should be fine.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZHBXNypg_D0  

What do you think?

Comment: @JeffPadgett I see, index of subcollection could be shared, but only limit to query for each parent document

Comment: What exactly is firebase-creds on this code snippet? I've been trying to use where equals, order by and limit on the same query with no success. I tried creating the indexes through the CLI and Firebase Console but I can't seem to make it work...

Comment: To anyone reading this, if you're having trouble figuring out the custom indexes, the node.js on this answer will probably work for you. I found out that firebase-creds is the Service Account JSON file you generate for your app on the Google Cloud Platform. Then I accessed the Firebase Console and, from the settings menu, generated the file. Please do note that you'll have to edit the node.js file on this answer to match your own database.

Answer (score 17):

This appears to be answered by @michael-bleigh here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47165007/2511985

> Cloud Firestore indexes are based on **collection names**, not full collection paths. So if you want to create indexes on `users/{id}/messages`, the correct way to do this is to create an index on `messages`.