# Cloud Firestore wildcard for indexing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What is the syntax for a wildcard level in Cloud Firestore when setting up indexing?  I know there is one for security rules.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Cloud Firestore indexes are based on **collection names**, not full collection paths. So if you want to create indexes on `users/{id}/messages`, the correct way to do this is to create an index on `messages`.

All same-named collections, even if nested under documents, share the same indexes.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  One more question, how would I do this for wildcard collections? would I do users/projects/{id} ?

Comment: Again, just use the collection name. So `users/{id}/projects/{id}` would be indexed by a `projects` index. The order goes collection/doc/collection/doc always, and you can always index by using the right-most collection name in the path.

Comment: Suppose I have messages in two places in my data model like `users/{id}/messages` and `groups/{id}/messages`. Is it possible to index only user messages and not group messages ?

Comment: This is important enough to be mentioned in Firestore documentation explicitly, I believe. Knowing this in advance would have made me name my subcollections differently. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @maganap Exactly!