# How to add an index to a Firebase sub-collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

---

#### I have some sub-collections in Firebase Cloud Firestore that I wish to add an index to.

### How can that be achieved ?

---

The [firebase instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for this say to click **add index** in the Index tab of the Firestore panel, but I have not been able to get that to work:

- If I put the full path to the subcollection into the **add index** dialog, then there is a red error saying "Collection ID {path} is reserved".
- I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981236/1290746), which says to use just the collection *name* (ie. the last part of the path), rather than the full path.  However, when I do that the "Create Index" button of the add index dialog never becomes enabled - thus I can't click the button to make the index.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

##### Scroll down in the dialog

This is super dumb - but I need to post this - because surely it will happen to someone else.

The reason the "Create index" button is not enabled is because there is more information to be entered - the dialog can scroll down, and then the additional option can be selected, and then the button becomes enabled:

[image]